# Wifi with Asus R510JK on ubuntu 15.04 and kernel 4.0

Tags: wireless, asus, 15.04

Wifi on this laptop was working well with ubuntu 14.10. I installed the daily 15.04 with kernel 4.0 in order to activate the FocalTech touchpad. But now the Wifi is not working anymore  (it's not working with the 15.04 stock kernel v3.19 also).

I'm looking for some clues on how to fix this problem.

lspci :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M] (rev a2)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`

`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` in the 3.19 kernel

[bcmwl with kernel 4.0 bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1424676)

Also check `lsmod | grep acer` and see if acer_wmi is listed, then

```
echo "blacklist acer_wmi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have a deb file that contains the patched version for the v4.0 kernel?

Comment: I am waiting for a different patch as I can't get the one from the bug report to work

Comment: me neither... did you achieved to make the focaltech touchpad working on 3.19?

Comment: http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms/ubuntu/pool/main/f/focaltech-dkms/focaltech-dkms_1.1_all.deb  Should get the focaltech touchpad working in 3.19

Comment: Thanks! I managed to build the deb file from the github master branch and it's compiling. I will reboot to test. Here the deb file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6FmWGouUs0YVVNGSU9RamRQVzQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: OK, everything is working well with v4.0 and this deb file.

Answer (score 0):

Focaltech will work on 3.19 for vivid.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install focaltech-dkms
```